# As part of hiring process, I've been asked to join a 1 day stage at a company. What should I expect?

Tags: interviewing, new-job

As part of hiring process, I've been asked to join a 1 day stage at a company. I've been told that I will work on assignments with the team.

What kind of assignments do you think I'm gonna receive? Probably some assignments that require to communicate requirements with other team members, or do they just want to stare at my screen on my laptop to see how I proceed making decisions and coding?

I'm iOS developer, this is a company deploying a mobile app.

Thanks

Comment: There is little point trying to second guess this.

Comment: Out of interest, are you getting paid for this trial day?

Comment: Nope. Indeed I'm not very happy about it. But I'm wondering,... It's very common that companies give a home assignment, they claim it takes 3-4 hours to finish, but it usually takes 1 day, or 1 day and half)... For all candidates doing such assignment, they also don't get paid right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do they just want to stare at my screen on my laptop to see how I proceed making decisions and coding?

If they just wanted to do that, chances are they would have just given you a take home exercise. This will almost certainly (primarily) be a test of how well you work with, and fit into the team, while performing some simulated task.

Generally speaking, they'll probably be looking for you to:

- Pipe up and present ideas where necessary;
- Challenge other's ideas where you believe they're wrong / incomplete;
- ...but ensure you're only doing the above two points in moderation, and you're not going to be one of these people who stomps all over everyone else just to get their point heard.

It's a balancing act, but if you're constantly mindful of these points then you put yourself in a good position.

Comment: I would also add that these extended interviews can give also to _you_ a very good glimpse of the company, the team, how the work is managed and what you would work on.
So there is added value also for the developer.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you're interviewing them also. Treat it like you would any working session with a client, and get to know the people you're working with. We can't tell what they're looking for (apart from a days free labor from you), but I'd recommend that you go in with an open mind and see if you enjoy the people and the experience.

(personally.. if a client wanted a whole day for something like this, I'd consider that a big red flag of an unorganized company, and would look elsewhere. But that's me...)